# Load Html content into jQuery variable

Tags: php, jquery, file-get-contents

I am trying below code to load html content to jquery variable.

```
<html>
  <body>
   <div id="static-content"></div>

   <?php        
     $static_content = file_get_contents('cms/content.php');
   ?>

   <script>


 $(document).ready(function($){  
    var static_content = '<?php echo $static_content; ?>';
    $('#static-content').load(static_content);  

  });     

   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am reading the html from content.php and try to append to div.

Its not working for me. Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: In php script $contnet changes to $content

Comment: If there are newlines or quotes in the text you load, you need `var static_content = \`<?php echo $content; ?>\`; ` But why not `$('#static-content').load("content.php")`

Comment: why don't just `<?php echo $content; ?>` inside the `div` directly?... if you still want to store the `$content` in javascript variable, you need to follow @mplungjan advice..

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien, Yes i can use like that, that i am trying for different purpose as per my requirement, so i am posting only this much here

Comment: @mplungjan, i am tried this code. $('#static-content').load("content.php"); can i use like this?

Comment: @jafarpinjar Yes you can. Look in the console for errors and in the network tab for 404s

Comment: @mplungjan, yes i used like below $('#static-content').load(static_content); but getting this error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: Alternative: `$.get("content.php",function(data) {  $('#static-content').append(data) });`

Comment: So the php data is not valid HTML/JSON/XML

Comment: I have updated my question based on ur answers, please check once,

Comment: Your amended code makes no sense. Why not just `<div id="static-content">
   <?php        
     echo file_get_contents('cms/content.php');
   ?></div>`

Comment: @mplungjan, pls understand, that is not my intention, i have already some html. so the id "static-content" is exist in somewhere in the html. for that purpose i am using like this, I need append the html content from the file i am trying now.

Comment: Try `$('#static-content').load(\`<?php echo $static_content; ?>\`);` NOTE the backtics!

Comment: @mplungjan, now getting below error, Uncaught SyntaxError: Unterminated template literal

Comment: Then you are doing it wrong or ALSO have backticks in the loaded content

Comment: @mplungjan, as i checked backtick is not there anywhere, but where i am wrong i don't know. Can you please tell where i am wrong

Comment: Try pasting into the browser: `view-source:http://yourwebsite/cms/content.php` and ctrl-f and search for `\``

Comment: @mplungjan, yes i checked it, only two times i can see back quotes

Comment: So you have them in the content.php and your use of backticks around the data request will fail.

Comment: You have not convinced us of your use case. WHY can't you just echo the content.php directly into the div???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185241/discussion-between-jafar-pinjar-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 1):

Try this ajax load concept. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id="static-content"> </div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('#static-content').load("content.php");
    });
```

Comment: hi @VinothRaj, its not working for me, getting Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in console

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay Why would removing a semicolon make the error go away???

Comment: @mplungjan, I thought its a syntax error. So thought to correct it.

Comment: It is a NOP statement and does not harm in that context

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, same its not working. content.php have html with class for divs

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
   <body>

    <div id="static-content"></div>
   <?php
      $myfile = fopen("content.php", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
      $content = fread($myfile,filesize("content.php"));
      fclose($myfile);
   ?>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function($){  
      var static_content = '<?php echo $content; ?>'; 
      console.log('htmltext ',static_content);
      $('#static-content').html(static_content);
      });     

   </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var static_content = '<?php echo $content; ?>'; ` will fail if there are any single quotes or newlines in the file

Comment: Yes for that any fix there?

Comment: @mplungjan, backticks(`) are not working in IE browser?